# What does it mean to make a method static in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'am a newbie in Python, however I'am fondling a code, which is more of encapsulation methods/functions in a class. The IDE underlined my code and gave me the option to make my method static, which I did. Notably they gave me the same output as my normal code.

**My Normal Code**

```
class firstClass():
    def method1(self):
        print "My first method defined in a Class"

    def method2(self, somestring):
        print "My second method in a Class: " + somestring


def main(c=firstClass()):
    c.method1()
    c.method2("somestring")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**My IDE-Edited code**

```
class firstClass():
    @staticmethod  # What is the meaning of this line really?
    def method1():
        print "My first method defined in a Class"

    @staticmethod
    def method2(somestring):
        print "My second method in a Class" + somestring, "\n"


def main(c=firstClass()):
    c.method1()
    c.method2("somestring")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I figured out that when IDE-Edited the method to `static`, it did pass in `@staticmethod` before my method as well as removed the `self` argument passed into the method. But I do not understand what a static method is all about in Python. What does it mean to make a method static in Python?

Comment: Thanks @JimFasarakis-Hilliard. But I will prefer I get an answer for my level. Just started learning Python.

Comment: Hm, what part of the top-answers' discussion on static methods confuses you? I can clarify it here for you.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard I think I found one self-explanatory answer in one of those answers, for a Python infant like me, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33727452/5614748. The provide blog link too was helpful.